# Default Archive Group in Gnus

Tags: emacs, archiving, gnus

I am using the following code to archive replies to messages in the same group they come from; it works well.

```lisp
;; Store sent messages in the same group they came from
(setq gnus-message-archive-method '(nnml ""))

(setq gnus-message-archive-group
        '((lambda (x)
            (cond
             ;; Store personal mail messages in the same group I started out in
             ((string-match ".*" group) group)
             ;; Store everything else in misc until I can sort it out
             (t "mail.misc")))))
```

However, if I use `C-x m` from a non-GNUs buffer, or create a message without a group selected, there seems to be no archiving at all; the message is lost unless I manually fill in a `GCC: mail.misc` line. How can I make this happen automatically for all messages not made from within a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set gnus as mail handler.

```lisp
(setq mail-user-agent 'gnus-user-agent)
```

Still this doesn't work, if gnus is not running when starting to
write a mail with C-x m.  Here a advice helps.

```lisp
(defadvice gnus-msg-mail (before start-gnus activate)
  (require 'gnus-start)
  (unless (gnus-alive-p)
    (save-window-excursion
      (let ((inhibit-redisplay t))
        (gnus)))))
```